# Can I use Java 16 record with JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-record

I am trying to do something similar like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Sample")
public record Sample(Integer id, String name) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String name;

}
```

However, it gives me error "User declared non-static fields id are not permitted in a record"
and same for name field as well.

Is there a way to use new java feature "record" with JPA annotation?

Comment: No records break multiple requirements of a classic JPA entity. Entities shouldn't be final, a no-args constructor is required and the attributes can not be final.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## tl;dr

No support currently, but likely later in 2024.

## Future

According to [*Jakarta EE 11: The Next Major Jakarta EE Update Is Shaping Up*](https://newsroom.eclipse.org/eclipse-newsletter/2023/august/jakarta-ee-11-next-major-jakarta-ee-update-shaping) by Ivar Grimstad, 2023-08:

- In [*Jakarta Persistence 3.2*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.2/), “Java Records will be usable as an embeddable type”.
- [*Jakarta Validation 3.1*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.1/) will add support for Java Records.

## Present

See the article, [*Using Records as Projections in JPA*](https://wkorando.github.io/sip-of-java/015.html) by Billy Korando. The following is a brief summary.

### Records cannot be Entities

[*Jakarta Persistence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence)  (*JPA*; formerly *Java Persistence API*) implementations such as [*Hibernate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)) depend on features either forbidden or not recommended by the [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) spec: no-arg constructors, non-final fields, setters, etc.

➥ So, no, records cannot be used as JPA `Entity`.

### Other uses of records

You can use records with:

- `CriteriaBuilder`
- `TypedQuery`
- `NativeQuery`
- Mapping definition

Spring data has some support as well.

See that article linked above for details, and for links to two other articles.

Comment: Is there at least any discussion around making JPA Entities compatible with Records? It would help a lot IMHO...

Comment: @Wojtek Yes, there is such discussion. See [*Jakarta EE 11: The Next Major Jakarta EE Update Is Shaping Up*](https://newsroom.eclipse.org/eclipse-newsletter/2023/august/jakarta-ee-11-next-major-jakarta-ee-update-shaping) by Ivar Grimstad, 2023-08. In Jakarta Persistence 3.2, “Java Records will be usable as an embeddable type”. And Jakarta Validation 3.1 will add support for Java Records.